# Changing focus on wx.panel

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets, wxtextctrl

Im writing an app which contains rich text panel with scoll.
Im doing some manipulations on the text and sometimes after certain action I need to write the text all over again on the screen, but I want the focus to be where it was before the action occured.
is it possible to change focus on the screen to a specific caret position?
Thanks.

Comment: are using wxRTC r wxTextCtrl?

Comment: I am using wxRTC.

Comment: can you please help me?

Comment: טולדנו, Are you talking about caret position in the wxRTC or the control focus? Also, what kind of action we are talkn g about - can you give a complete scenario?